# How to delete dynamically allocated array in destructor in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYP3K.png)

As you can see, the destructor complains "Use of undeclared identifier 'a'

Is my array out of scope? How can i delete it, when i call the destructor?

Comment: Please copy and paste the code into your question instead of attaching a screenshot.

Comment: Please don't link to code. Include all relevant code *in* the question as a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`a` has to be a member variable of the class. As you  have it now its a local

Answer (score 0):

`a` needs to be a data member of `hashtable` in order for this to work. Right now it is a variable local to the constructor, and the memory allocation is therefore leaked when the constructor terminates.

However, even if you correct this problem, beware the rule of five: if you implement any of the following you need to implement or delete *all* of them:

- Destructor
- Copy constructor
- Copy-assignment operator
- Move constructor
- Move-assignment operator

If you do not, the compiler will generate them for you and *it will get them wrong* in this case.  Simply copying the pointer value to the new object is not enough; a new allocation needs to be made and the contents copied (except in the case of a move).  The compiler-generated versions *will* result in a use-after-free or double-delete.

You can avoid all of this by using `std::vector<int>` instead of trying to manage your own memory.